# How to verify that an annotation is only used on certain classes?

Tags: java, annotations

Say I have an annotation `@Annotate` and a class `A`. How can I check whether `@Annotate` is used on class `A` and its subclasses only (probably at compile time)?

So, if we have:

```
/* Example 1 */

public class A {

}  

public class B extends A {

}

public class C {

}
```

How do I check that class `A` and class `B` can be annotated by `@Annotate` but class `C` is not allowed (and might raise a compile error).

---

If we go with the decision that this would be checked at compile time:

```
/* Example 2 */

public class A {

}  

@Annotate
public class B extends A {

}
```

*Example 2* will not raise a compile time error because `@Annotate` is used on a subclass of `A`. *Example 3*, however, will raise an compile error because `@Annotate` is not used on a subclass of `A`.

```
/* Example 3 */

@Annotate
public class C {

}
```

However, this does not have to be checked at compile time in anyway. I just personally thought that it makes sense to do so.

Comment: What do you mean by "check if annotation is present at compile time"? An annotation has something called RetentionPolicy which is marked on the source code of the annotation. You can always open the source code for the annotation and check to see its RetentionPolicy

Comment: I did not meant to check if the annotation is __present__. I meant to check if the annotation is used on only the certain classes. I am fully aware of the `RetentionPolicy` and `ElementType` annotations.

Comment: By what logic is it not allowed on class `C`? It sounds like you have some custom ad-hoc rules for this. You could probably implement as a `javax.annotation.processing` annotation processor for javac.

Comment: How do you check if a annotation is used **at compile time**. When the application is running, the annotation with a `RetentionPolicy.COMPILE` would not be abailable.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Can you please demonstrate?

Comment: @krismath No, that's far too broad a topic. You could search for some examples on Google using the javax.annotation.processing name I gave you above. The following example in this blog looks similar enough to what you want: https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/core-java-tutorial/java-se-annotation-processing-api/annotation-processor-validation.html

Comment: @Prashant I have added an example. Seems that you misunderstood my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write an [annotation processor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/Processor.html).  An annotation processor can generate new Java files and, more relevantly for your case, issue compile-time warnings.

You will invoke it at compile time by running the java compiler like this:  `javac -processor MyProcessor MyFile.java`.  If regular javac or your annotation processor issues any warnings, then compilation fails.

Your annotation processor's logic is specific to your `@Annotate` annotation and is simple:  permit the annotation only on classes that subclass `A`.  There are various tutorials on the web about how to write an annetation processor, in addition to the Oracle documentation I linked above.

Answer (score 1):

You can use my [`checker-framework`](https://github.com/XDean/Deannotation-checker).

Just Simply add annotation `@CheckType` on your annotation

```
@Target(TYPE)
@CheckType(value = A.class, type = Type.EXTEND_ALL)
public @interface OnlyOnA {
}
```

Now it can check if it is annotated on A or its subclass.

It will raise a compile error

- eclipse snapshot

[image]

- maven snapshot

[image]